# How to imperatively validate AAD token?

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have a .NET Core 6 app that uses a custom authentication scheme. Here's part of my `Startup.cs`:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(HybridAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddScheme<HybridAuthenticationOptions, HybridAuthenticationHandler>(HybridAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => { });
```

Here's the key part of `HybridAuthenticationHandler`:

```
if (await this.ValidateNonAADToken(httpRequestMessage, SignedRequestScope) ||
    this.ValidateCertificate(this.Context) ||
    // I WANT AAD TOKEN VALIDATION TO GO HERE) {
    // AUTH SUCCEEDS
}
```

I want to add validation of an AAD token using the [Microsoft.Identity.Web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/microsoft-identity-web) NuGet package as a fallback to the existing two authentication methods.

Is there an imperative AAD token validation method I could use in `HybridAuthenticationHandler` as another OR condition?

If I chain AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi() after AddScheme() in `Startup.cs` (which the docs [describe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-api-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet-core#startup-class) as the standard method), will that somehow overwrite my custom authentication handler? If it will simply add the AAD token check as a fallback authentication method in case my custom handler fails, that could work for me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JwtSecurityTokenHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler?view=azure-dotnet) which exposes several Validate* methods.

If no IssuerValidator has been set, you can use [MicrosoftIdentityIssuerValidatorFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.resource.microsoftidentityissuervalidatorfactory?view=azure-dotnet) for multitenant v1 and v2 validation.

Calling [AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.microsoftidentitywebapiauthenticationbuilderextensions.addmicrosoftidentitywebapi?view=azure-dotnet) will add the [JwtBearerHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerhandler?view=aspnetcore-6.0) but not overwrite any other handler unless the schema name is the same.